# Datos vacíos con GET fetch en node

Tags: nodejs, api, axios, fetch, get

Buenas me encuentro haciendo un get en fetch, este es mi codigo

```
const usersFounded = []
        var id = [
            '1234',
            '1213',
            '3433',
            '3455',
            '2424',
          ]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
                fetch(`https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/${id}/profile?hapikey=${ hapikey }`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data)
                    usersFounded.push(data)        
                })
                .catch((error) =>{
                    console.log("Error al encontrar los contactos")
                    console.log(error);
                    
                })
                console.log("contactos encontrados")
                console.log(usersFounded); 
          }
```

me  pidieron extraer los datos de 5 id por lo tanto los encasille en una variable llamada id y los llame en mi api, luego guardo los resultados en usersFounded = [].
Pero al dar send en postman se me muestra lo siguiente en cosola

```
contactos encontrados
[]
contactos encontrados
[]
contactos encontrados
[]


    {
  status: 'error',
  message: 'Unable to parse value for path parameter: vid',
}   
  status: 'error',
  message: 'Unable to parse value for path parameter: vid',
}  
  status: 'error',
  message: 'Unable to parse value for path parameter: vid',
}
```

Me entregan los 3 resultados vacíos porque será ?, soy nuevo en esto

Comment: estas enviando el arreglo lo la posicion es `${id[i]}` o cambiarlo por `for (let i of id) {`

Comment: gracias bro, me sirvio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar el [i-ésimo elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#operaciones_habituales) de los ids: `${id[i]}`, de otro modo siempre se está usando la ruta `"https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/1234,1213,3433,3455,2424..."`, la cuál no existe.

Comment: muchas gracias bro